# Meaning of curly brackets and colons?

Tags: python

Homework question:

Write a function which is called like: `replace_all({'a':'123', 'b':'Zab'}, 'acb')`

What does the function declaration look like?

What kind of variable is `'a':'123'` and `{}`?

Comment: did they provide a sample output for the function?

Comment: Lucky to do Python as homework :-) We had Pascal.

Answer (score 3):

It's a dictionary (mapping).

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.

Generally, when you define function in python, you don't need types. Python is dynamically typed language.

Comment: Also read up on Dictionaries here: http://diveintopython.org/native_data_types/index.html#odbchelper.dict

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is the empty dictionary, `{'a':'123'}` is a dictionary with a key `'a'` that has the associated value `'123'`

the function would look like:

```
def replace_all(replace_map, string):
    pass # fill in here
```

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations in Python do not involve any types, because variables in Python don't have types - **values** have types.

You don't declare the function separately, you just write it. The first line of a function looks like `def name_of_function(arguments, go, here):`. In your case, there are two things that are being passed: `{'a': '123', 'b': 'Zab'}`, and `'acb'`. So you need to specify two arguments, and give them names.

`{'a': '123', 'b': 'Zab'}` is a single "thing" - `'a': '123'` is meaningless on its own. The whole thing is a **value**, not a variable. The type of the value is `dict`. The value represents a logical mapping: that is, the value encodes the concept of "'a' corresponds to '123', and 'b' corresponds to 'Zab'".

I assume, given the name `replace_all`, that the intent is to look at every character in 'acb', and replace it with the corresponding value (if any) from the dict.

You get "the corresponding value" from a `dict` by using the "key" as an index. Thus, if you have the **value** `{'a': '123', 'b': 'Zab'}` bound to the **variable** `my_dict`, then evaluating `my_dict['a']` gives the result `'123'`, since that is the value associated with the 'a' key in that `dict`. If the key isn't actually in the dict (for example `my_dict['c']`), this will raise `KeyError`. You can either handle the exception, or else use one of the "safe" access functions, such as the `.get` method of the `dict`. Refer to the documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of such a function is " def replace_all(Dictionary, String): ". with the '{}' is designating a dictionary data structure of python in which 'a', 'b' are keys and they have there own corresponding values." 'a':'123' " is called an item of the dictionary (if you are considering " 'a':'123' " in context of this same dictionary otherwise it is a string) and they can be retrieved as a tuple.

For further details just look into the python manual for dictionary and dict.items()